# Não grava registros no meu banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Criei um sistema de cadastro, mais quando eu clicko no botão cadastrar aparece a mensagem "Não foi possível inserir registro:"... Alguém pode identificar esse erro, pois eu até agora não consegui identifica-lo. Segue meu código abaixo.

**cadastro.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sistema de cadastro</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="signup" method="post" action="cadastrando.php">
nome: <input type="text" name"nome" /><br /><br />
sobrenome: <input type="text" name="sobrenome" /><br /><br />
e-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br />
senha: <input type="password" name="senha" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="cadastrar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**cadastrando.php**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cadastrando...</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php


$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = null;
$banco = 'dbcadastro';
$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$banco);
// verifica a conexao
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Erro ao conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
  <?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO `usuarios`('', 'nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 'senha'");
}
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel inserir registro: " . mysql_error());
}
echo "<br />Um novo registro foi feito!";

?>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: o código da pergunta já foi editado, por isso o erro que gerou a pergunta já nem sequer faz sentido. a pergunta que fizeste já está respondida, e por isso já mudaste a parte de HTML. tens muitos outros erros no código, que já foram mencionados por várias pessoas, mas se tens outros erros, cria novas perguntas.

Comment: Ruan, fico feliz que tenha achado a solução para seu problema no [pt.so]! Porém, só uma dica, não precisa arrumar o código da perguntam, caso contrário quem for ver a questão depois não vai entender o que aconteceu. Abraço!

Comment: Ok, não farei as edições,Obrigado!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se fizeres `print_r($_POST)` vais ver que não existe uma variavel chamada `'submit'` no array do `$_POST`. Esse é o problema. Tens de definir o ID / Name do `submit` `button` no HTML.

```
<input type="submit" value="cadastrar"/>
```

O que isto faz:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

é procurar por um campo chamado submit nos campos do formulario que foi submetido. O `form` que tem na sua pergunta não tem nenhum campo com esse nome. Se fizer `print_r($_POST)` consegue consultar os campos existentes na variavel `$_POST`.

Agora é que reparei que esse código tem mais coisas erradas.

Falta um `else` aqui, antes da linha do `die`:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO `usuarios`('', 'nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 'senha'");
}
{
  die("<br />Nao foi possivel inserir registro: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Como assim um submit no array do POST? Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: @RuanRodrigues expliquei na resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Parece que você não passou os valores corretos o no `insert` e sim apenas `strings`, adicione o sinal de cifrão nas variáveis

```
sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES('', '$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha'") or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

Para os valores do `form` serem reconhecidos pelo php é obrigatório informar o atributo `name`, seu `submit` não tem ele.

Adicione um `name`, no caso deve-se chamar `submit` como esta no `if`

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="cadastrar">
```

Comment: Continuou aparecendo a mensagem de erro =/ ^^

Comment: Não faltou o VALUES ali? `insert into usuarios VALUES ()...`

Comment: @RuanRodrigues e o erro é o mesmo? se é, você não corrigiu o <input> correctamente. se for outro, é porque o query está mal, e está. mas isso já não diz respeito ao erro da pergunta que colocou.

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="cadastrar">, está certo?

Comment: @RuanRodrigues como lhe disse na minha resposta, faça print_r ao post e confirme.

Comment: Array ( [sobrenome] => Rodrigues [email] => ruan@gmail.com [senha] => 123456 [submit] => cadastrar ) , acho que o erro está na minha variável $nome, pq ela não esta aparecendo...

Comment: se é isso que aparece no print_r, então o erro que estava a aparecer quando colocou a pergunta já não aparece.

Comment: @RuanRodrigues na minha resposta coloquei outro erro que está no codigo. e o query está mal, mas isso já não diz respeito à pergunta colocada.

Comment: @rafael withoeft, obrigado pela correção, editei a resposta.

Comment: @rray Por nada :)

Comment: Bom... Eu tentei todas as soluções mais continua à aparecer o  "Nao foi possivel inserir registro:"

Comment: O die() esta dentro do else ou solto?

Comment: ele está solto.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 @rray , apareceu isso após ser feita sua edição

Comment: Troque o '' por null em VALUES(''.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, sinceramente isso foi algo `"OMG"`.
O teu erro está no formulário HTML, no `input de envio`, tu escreveste algo assim:

```
<input type="submit" value="cadastrar"/>
```

E depois tentaste verificar com o `PHP` se foi definida alguma variável to tipo `POST` com nome `submit` quando nem sequer especificaste um atributo `name`.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
...
```

O correto seria fazeres algo assim no `HTML`:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="cadastrar"/>
```

E também falta o `VALUES` do `SQL`, veja a sintaxe correta:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2) VALUES (valor1, valor2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Esta consulta SQL esta errada, você não especificou a quais colunas esta inserindo qual valor é muito provavel que esteja inserido valor de uma colunaa em outra e dando um erro de tipo, ela tambem não esta com o `VALUES` a forma adequada seria:

```
"INSERT INTO usuarios (coluna1,coluna2,coluna3,coluna4) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')";
```

Substitua as `colunas` pelas colunas onde irão armazenar os valores, lembre-se que devem estar na mesma ordem `coluna / valor`

Answer (score -2):

Simplifique seu código para que o mesmo possa encontrar uma semântica, use as condições coerente para que seu algoritmo seja de fácil interpretação para você e outros re-utilizarem / modificar / aprimora.

```
if (!empty=$nome && !empty=sobrenome...................) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (nome,email..........) VALUES ($nome,$email.......)";

}else
{
  die(trigger_error("<br />Nao foi possivel inserir registro: " . mysql_error()));
}
```

Comment: `!empty=$nome` não é uma sintaxe válida no PHP